# iOS CoreData - are there any disadvantages to enabling sqlite WAL / Write-Ahead Logging

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data

At the WWDC 2013 session '207: What's New in Core Data', they mention that you can enable SQLite WAL by passing an options dictionary when adding a persistent store:

```
@{ NSSQLitePragmasOption: @"journal_mode = WAL" }
```

(which is available on iOS4+ and will be the default for future iOS versions).

I'm wondering whether this would generally be a good thing to enable in my app for earlier iOS versions too.

I've consulted the [SQLite page about write ahead logging](http://sqlite.org/wal.html) and the disadvantages they mention, most of them seem not to apply to iOS apart from:

- WAL might be very slightly slower (perhaps 1% or 2% slower) than the
  traditional rollback-journal approach in applications that do mostly
  reads and seldom write.

pretty much all the advantages do sound like they'll probably be a benefit on iOS:

- WAL is significantly faster in most scenarios.
- WAL provides more concurrency as readers do not block writers and a writer does not block readers. Reading and writing can proceed concurrently.
- Disk I/O operations tends to be more sequential using WAL.
- WAL uses many fewer fsync() operations and is thus less vulnerable to problems on systems where the fsync() system call is broken.

I'm asuming (perhaps subject to doing some checks on my app to make sure it doesn't slow things down) that this would be a good thing to enable, but is there any downside I should watch for or any known issues?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

http://pablin.org/2013/05/24/problems-with-core-data-migration-manager-and-journal-mode-wal/ suggests that their could be issues with migrations, in particular:

> When you use a Migration Manager, Core Data will create a new database
>   for you, and start copying the entities one by one from the old DB to
>   the new one.
>
> As we are using journal_mode = WAL, there’s an additional file besides
>   DB.sqlite called DB.sqlite-wal.
>
> From what I can tell, the problem seems to be that Core Data creates a
>   temporary DB, inserts everything there, and when it renames it to the
>   original name, the -wal file is kept as a leftover from the old
>   version. The problem is that you end up with an inconsistent DB.

(also mentioned on https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/issues/490 - which suggests that if you use magical record then it is already defaulting to WAL )

Comment: I should note that this only happens in the "advanced" migrations, when you need a Migration Manager. Less radical migrations (like adding or renaming a column) will work just fine, as they are performed on the same database and not in a copy.

Comment: Couldn't you temporarily disable WAL, deleting the journal (-wal file), and then do the migration ...?

Comment: Migration of db generally happens during start of an application. Doesn't this mean that the checkpoint must already have run during the last application close?

Comment: @Him The problem is just during an advanced migration where coredata fails to rename a file correctly. The workaround mentioned in the linked blog post, specifying journal_mode = DELETE when the app detects a migration needs to happen, avoids that file existing when the migration happens.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the bug that occurs with non-lightweight migrations that involve subclassing NSMigrationManager, which I've re-reported to Apple as Bug 16038419.

I've also made a different, [method-swizzling workaround](https://github.com/jerrykrinock/CategoriesObjC/blob/master/NSPersistentStoreCoordinator+PatchRollback.h) which patches the bug in cases where you *always* want to use legacy delete/rollback journaling.  As I understand it, [Pablin's fix](http://pablin.org/2013/05/24/problems-with-core-data-migration-manager-and-journal-mode-wal/) is for cases when you want to use WAL *except* during migrations.   Also, you can see that bug occur in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=daSf7n78NPM).

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Out of interest, in what cases would you want to always avoid WAL?

Comment: Case 1:  Mac OS X Core Data app not using file packages.  The sqlite file is the document file.  Users scratch heads when they see -shm and -wal files adjacent to their documents in Finder.  They may think these are junk and either trash them, or ignore them when moving or copying the document file.  Result: data loss.

Case 2: "WAL journal_mode is not, however, recommended for read-only database files, or for files that need to interoperate with iOS 4 or earlier."  That is from:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DataManagement/WhatsNew_CoreData_iOS/