# Data not being saved to core data

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cocoa-touch, core-data

I am using Xcode 5 compiling exclusively for iOS 7.

I am reading data from a UTF8 txt file to populate a core data entity. After reading the data, I log it to the console. The data is there. I populate the entity and log the entity to the console. I save it. No error. No crash.

I see 3 files on the device:

- MyDatabase.sqlite
- MyDatabase.sqlite-shm
- MyDatabase.sqlite-wal

When the app starts and `MyDatabase.sqlite` is created empty it has 40 kb. At this point the `shm` file is 32kb and the `wal` file is zero.

After I write the data to the database, the `wal` files grows to 1,7 Mb but the other two files keep their initial sizes or in other words, the data is not being saved to the database. I have confirmed that by inspecting the sqlite file with an external database viewer.

This is the code I am using:

```
// NSArray *arrayOfYears = ... 
// this contains an array of numbers read from the CSV file
// at this point the array contains numbers in text format

// NSArray *arrayOfBrands = ...
// this is an array of brands

for (int i=0; i<[arrayOfBrands count]; i++) {

            Cars *car = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Cars" inManagedObjectContext:context];

            car.brand = [arrayOfBrands objectAtIndex:i];
            car.year = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[arrayOfYears objectAtIndex:i] integerValue]];

            NSError *error = nil;
            if (![context save:&error]) {
                // Handle the error.
                NSLog(@"error = %@", error);
            }
}
```

This produces no error or crash. It goes like it was saving. I have increased mySql debug level to 3 and this is what I see on console...

**when the table is created empty**

```
CoreData: annotation: Connecting to sqlite database file at "/var/mobile/Applications/BB22334C4-550A-4C44-B17A-3F02062EC687/Documents/MyDatabase.sqlite"
CoreData: annotation: creating schema.
CoreData: sql: pragma page_size=4096
CoreData: sql: pragma auto_vacuum=2
CoreData: sql: BEGIN EXCLUSIVE
CoreData: sql: SELECT TBL_NAME FROM SQLITE_MASTER WHERE TBL_NAME = 'Z_METADATA'
CoreData: sql: CREATE TABLE ZCARS ( Z_PK INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Z_ENT INTEGER, Z_OPT INTEGER, ZYEAR INTEGER, ZBRAND VARCHAR ) 
CoreData: annotation: Creating primary key table.
CoreData: sql: CREATE TABLE Z_PRIMARYKEY (Z_ENT INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Z_NAME VARCHAR, Z_SUPER INTEGER, Z_MAX INTEGER)
CoreData: sql: INSERT INTO Z_PRIMARYKEY(Z_ENT, Z_NAME, Z_SUPER, Z_MAX) VALUES(1, 'Cars', 0, 0)
CoreData: sql: CREATE TABLE Z_METADATA (Z_VERSION INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Z_UUID VARCHAR(255), Z_PLIST BLOB)
CoreData: sql: SELECT TBL_NAME FROM SQLITE_MASTER WHERE TBL_NAME = 'Z_METADATA'
CoreData: sql: DELETE FROM Z_METADATA WHERE Z_VERSION = ?
CoreData: details: SQLite bind[0] = 1
CoreData: sql: INSERT INTO Z_METADATA (Z_VERSION, Z_UUID, Z_PLIST) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
CoreData: details: SQLite bind[0] = 1
CoreData: details: SQLite bind[1] = "C6E2268B-6792-4298-B292-5025E5BDE31A"
CoreData: details: SQLite bind[2] = <NSData len=455>
CoreData: annotation: Saving new meta data; version = 1 ; UUID = C6E2268B-6792-4298-B292-5025E5BDE31A
CoreData: sql: COMMIT
CoreData: sql: pragma journal_mode=wal
CoreData: sql: pragma journal_mode=wal
CoreData: sql: pragma cache_size=200
CoreData: sql: SELECT Z_VERSION, Z_UUID, Z_PLIST FROM Z_METADATA
```

**after saving one brand/year**

```
CoreData: sql: BEGIN EXCLUSIVE
CoreData: sql: SELECT Z_MAX FROM Z_PRIMARYKEY WHERE Z_ENT = ?
CoreData: annotation: getting max pk for entityID = 4
CoreData: sql: UPDATE Z_PRIMARYKEY SET Z_MAX = ? WHERE Z_ENT = ? AND Z_MAX = ?
CoreData: annotation: updating max pk for entityID = 4 with old = 0 and new = 1
CoreData: sql: COMMIT
CoreData: sql: BEGIN EXCLUSIVE
CoreData: sql: INSERT INTO ZTABULEIRO(Z_PK, Z_ENT, Z_OPT, ZYEAR, ZBRAND) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
CoreData: details: SQLite bind[0] = (int64)1
CoreData: details: SQLite bind[1] = (int64)4
CoreData: details: SQLite bind[2] = (int64)1
CoreData: details: SQLite bind[3] = "FORD"
CoreData: details: SQLite bind[4] = (int64)1989
CoreData: sql: COMMIT
CoreData: annotation: Changing objectID 0x14e71730 <x-coredata:///Cars/t38FA86EE-4124-4FD7-A8C0-8CE7BBAC73782> to 0x14e73ef0 <x-coredata://C6E3368B-6792-4298-B292-5025E5BDE31A/Cars/p1>
CoreData: sql: pragma page_count
CoreData: annotation: sql execution time: 0.0014s
CoreData: sql: pragma freelist_count
CoreData: annotation: sql execution time: 0.0016s
```

one strange thing I see here is the year variable like int64 when I have defined it like integer 16. Why it is using integer 64 is beyond me...

The data is not being saved at all. The data is there. If I log the arrays of data to console I see the data. If I log the entities populated before saving I see the data.

I am testing this on a device running iOS 7. Thanks.

What am I missing? How do I debug that?

Comment: How many NSManagedObjectContexts do you have? Is this particular context associated with a NSPersistentStoreCoordinator?

Comment: as far as I know, one. Why do you ask that? Is there a way to have more than one? for what purpose?

Comment: If you have multiple contexts in a parent-child relationships, saves only go one level up. Saves to the file are only triggered by saving the root context. If you only have one context, this doesn't apply.

Comment: What you have said is Klingon to me, but as far as I know I just have one context.

Comment: Can you show the code where you set up the persistent store?

Comment: Thanks. Andy Etheridge nailed the problem. Thanks anyway for your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The data is being saved to the database if the write-ahead-log (wal) is increasing in size,  See documentation here http://www.sqlite.org/draft/wal.html.  What are you using to open the database file?  You must use a tool that works with WAL journal mode. Rather than looking at the db files directly, try creating a new context and fetching your saved entities.

Comment: you are right! I was inspecting just the sqlite file independently. The moment I copied the other two files to the same directory and inspected the database again, the database shows populated. Now here is the big question of them all: when the app starts for the first time, it has to copy the sqlite file from the bundle to the documents directory. What do I have to do now? Copy all 3 files from the bundle to the documents directory? The database is now not just one but 3 files? wtf! Or in other words: do I have to include these 3 files in the bundle, right?

Comment: or another alternative: there is a way to disable this wal thing on core data or to commit the changes to the sqlite file? Thanks

Comment: Yes.  See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18870387/core-data-and-ios-7-different-behavior-of-persistent-store/18870738#18870738

Comment: Why do you have to move the files?  Are you deploying with a pre-populated database?

Comment: yes. Thanks, I have managed to disabled this journal thing and now the total database has 128 kb instead of 3.3 MB!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @RubberDuck could you please state how you managed to disable it? Thanks

Comment: @user2512523 - I don't have the project right now but was basically by disabling the journal mode: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18870738/316469