# Changes are not saved to original persistent store

Tags: ios, macos, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have a small utility app which populates a persistent store that I package with an iPhone app.  I recently upgraded to OS X Maverick and now my app is behaving differently than it did before.  When this line executes:

[self.managedObjectContext save:&error]

...I now get two new files: my objects.datastore-wal and objets.datastore-shm. The new objects I am adding seem to be stored here instead of the original objects.datastore file, because deleting them reverts my changes.

Why are my changes not persisted to the original DB?  Am I missing a step here?  Is there some call I need to make to the PersistentStoreCoordinator?  This behavior is definitely different than I was seeing in Mountain Lion, when I always had just one file to work with.

Comment: See also [Core Data and iOS 7: Different behavior of persistent store](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18870387/core-data-and-ios-7-different-behavior-of-persistent-store).

Comment: If I am not wrong, there were some changes to how the records are stored in the datastore file starting from iOS7 (saw it in the WWDC 2013 Core Data videos). Possibly the same thing?

Comment: Thanks, I found link #2 there extremely helpful.