# CoreData: field returning nil when upgrading app

Tags: ios, core-data

I am using CoreData and experiencing the following:

- I install my app through the App Store. That build was built with the iOS 6 SDK.
- I run the app, and it stores something with CoreData.
- Then I upgrade the app through TestFlight (a new build done with the iOS 7 SDK) and the behaviour is not the expected one, seems that a NSManagedObject field is returning nil (I know it shouldn't make any difference, but I am accessing to it with `valueForKey:`).

Wanting to know what's going on, I uninstall the app, install it again from the App Store and run the version submitted to TestFlight from Xcode to debug it. I see that that valueForKey: is returning nil the first time I run the app, but the second time I follow the same steps(uninstalling and install from the App Store and then run with Xcode) the problem is gone. From this moment, if I follow the original steps(AppStore -> TestFlight) it always works as it should, that valueForKey: call is not returning nil anymore. Weird.

So, say that this is fixed on my device, but a team mate who never run the app with Xcode is experiencing the mentioned problem.

I have tried to set the persistent store options like commented in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18870387/core-data-and-ios-7-different-behavior-of-persistent-store) (submitting it to TestFlight), but it didn't help - my team mate is still experiencing the problem.

Have anyone had a similar issue before? Any idea about the cause of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Without running the application in Xcode, against a debug build you are not going to be able to debug this issue without a LOT of effort.

Whoever is developing the application should be running it in debug mode and can watch the console, set breakpoints, etc. to solve the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Marcus. The problem I have is that the issue only happens when installing from TestFlight. Do you think any of the iOS 7 changes in sqlite persistent stores could be the cause of my problem?

Comment: If it is only happening when you run the test flight build then I would suggest running that build configuration from Xcode, install the app store, then run the Xcode build and watch the console.  It will get you the information you need to solve this.

Comment: The problem is that only happens in my team mate's device. In mine (I have run the app through Xcode and then delete the app from the device) it works as it should... It's a very strange issue. Seems that running the app from Xcode somehow fixes the problem, even if after I delete the app, install from the App Store and the from TestFlight.

Comment: Phantom device bugs drive me crazy.  If you can plug their device into Xcode you should be able to grab the entire app bundle from the device and then try and replay it on another device. With luck it will give you a hint. If you can get their device at least plugged into Xcode you can try and look at their console for some hints.