# CoreData: error: (14) on device, not in simulator

Tags: ios, core-data, xcode5

I get this error when running on the device, not the simulator (now).

I did get the same error on simulator as well and implemented the solution from this thread:
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18870387/core-data-and-ios-7-different-behavior-of-persistent-store/18870738#18870738)

with this code:

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
if (__persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
    return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

//    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"engliah_FamQuiz.sqlite"];

//=== USE DATABASE FROM MAIN BUNDLE ===//
NSURL *storeURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:kNewDB withExtension:@"sqlite"];

// Use this for source store - ensures you don't accidentally write to the entities
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:1]
                                                     forKey:NSReadOnlyPersistentStoreOption];
// Make sure the WAL mode for Core Data is not enabled
   options = @{ NSSQLitePragmasOption : @{@"journal_mode" : @"DELETE"} }; <<< ADDED THIS LINE

//    NSDictionary *options = @{NSReadOnlyPersistentStoreOption : @YES, NSSQLitePragmasOption : @{@"journal_mode" : @"DELETE"} };

NSError *error = nil;
__persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
```

This solved the problem in the simulator but the app crash on the device with the following error:

```
2014-06-21 15:23:49.828 xxxx[30224:60b] Attempt to add read-only file at path file:///var/mobile/Applications/236047B5-0B0F-443D-ABCF-DCABA0166713/xxxx.app/yyyyy.sqlite read/write. Adding it read-only instead. This will be a hard error in the future; you must specify the NSReadOnlyPersistentStoreOption.
2014-06-21 15:23:49.838 xxxx[30224:60b] CoreData: error: (14) I/O error for database at /var/mobile/Applications/236047B5-0B0F-443D-ABCF-DCABA0166713/xxxx.app/yyyy.sqlite.  SQLite error code:14, 'unable to open database file'
2014-06-21 15:23:49.845 xxxx[30224:60b] Unresolved error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 256.)" UserInfo=0x16e48d80 {NSUnderlyingException=I/O error for database at /var/mobile/Applications/236047B5-0B0F-443D-ABCF-DCABA0166713/xxxx.app/yyyyy.sqlite.  SQLite error code:14, 'unable to open database file', NSSQLiteErrorDomain=14}, {
NSSQLiteErrorDomain = 14;
NSUnderlyingException = "I/O error for database at /var/mobile/Applications/236047B5-0B0F-443D-ABCF-DCABA0166713/xxxx.app/yyyy.sqlite.  SQLite error code:14, 'unable to open database file'";
```

In simulator there is no error. Also, the first error is also new.

Deployment target: 6.1

Comment: After writing my answer I saw that you added the same code as an comment in your question: `// NSDictionary *options = @{NSReadOnlyPersistentStoreOption : @YES, NSSQLitePragmasOption : @{@"journal_mode" : @"DELETE"} };`. - So which is your actual code now?

Comment: I assume that the SQLite file is bundled with the app. Did you also disable the WAL-mode when *creating* the database?

Comment: @MartinR no i did not disable the WAL when creating the DB, will test that now.

Comment: @MartinR that fixed the problem, a BIG thank you for your help. Please add this as an answer so i can mark it solved. I still not understand why it worked in the simulator but not the device.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code

```
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:1]
                                                forKey:NSReadOnlyPersistentStoreOption];
options = @{ NSSQLitePragmasOption : @{@"journal_mode" : @"DELETE"} };
```

sets `options` to a dictionary containing the `NSSQLitePragmasOption` key only, but not
the `NSReadOnlyPersistentStoreOption` key, because the second line overwrites the
dictionary assigned in the first line.

What you probably want is

```
NSDictionary *options = @{ 
    NSReadOnlyPersistentStoreOption : @YES,
    NSSQLitePragmasOption: @{@"journal_mode":@"DELETE"}
};
```

to create an `options` directory containing both keys.

In addition, you have also to disable the WAL-mode when *creating* the SQLite file
that is bundled with the application.

The problem does not occur in the Simulator because the application directory is 
read-write in the Simulator, but read-only on the device.

Comment: thanks, unfortunately i get the same error in the simulator this time :-(

Comment: The comment from MartinR, which was the solution: I assume that the SQLite file is bundled with the app. Did you also disable the WAL-mode when creating the database? –  Martin R 2 hours ago